# ¿Como puede obtener el id de un usuario?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, backend

tengo un proyecto en el que cuando el usuario inicia sesión se crea una variable de sesión con el campo usuario de mi formulario. Ahora quisiera saber como puedo obtener el id, es decir la llave primaria de un usuario a partir de una variable de sesión, y posteriormente insertar este valor como llave foránea en otra tabla. Este es el código php que tengo hasta el momento:

```html
<?php  
 include("Conexion.php");
 $titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
 $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
 $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
 session_start();
 $id = $_SESSION['Session'];
 $sql2 = "SELECT idusuario FROM usuario WHERE usuario='".$id."'";
 $resul = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error" .mysql_error());
 $sql = "INSERT INTO tarea VALUES(null,'".$titulo."','".$fecha."','".$descripcion."','".$resul."')";
 $resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error" .mysql_error());
 header("location: ../html/Tareas.php");
?>
```

Pero me envia el siguiente error:
ErrorCannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`apptic`.`tarea`, CONSTRAINT `fk_tarea_usuario` FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_idusuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`idusuario`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Espero puedan ayudarme y les agradezco.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la estructura de la tabla `tarea`?

Answer (score 1):

En esta linea del codigo

```
"INSERT INTO tarea VALUES (null,'".$titulo."','".$fecha."','".$descripcion."','".$resul."')";
```

Reemplazalo por

```
"INSERT INTO tarea VALUES ('".$id."','".$titulo."','".$fecha."','".$descripcion."','".$resul."')";
```

La llaves foráneas no deben tener un valor en `null`.

Comment: por otra parte, seria mas correcto que tu consulta tuviera el formato `INSERT INTO Table(field1, field2, field3...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3...)` para asegurarte que valores estas insertando en que campos.

Comment: ¿Como sabes que ese `null` no corresponde al `id` de la tarea? Se me ocurre que deberías pedir al OP la estructura de la tabla antes.